# How to hide some row item in listview with angular2 nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I need to remove/hide an item from the listview if a condition is met: both the getData and getCategory Name are equal.
I tested in console log, for the first three items the above two conditions are equal.

So based on that I need to hide the item.I tried below code.it doesn't worked for me.

**Edited:**

**html :**

```
<GridLayout >
    <ListView (setupItemView)="onSetupItemView($event)" [items]="allFeedItems" class="list-group">
        <ng-template let-item="item" let-visible="visible">
            <StackLayout [visibility]="visible ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'" class="card-view" margin="10">

            <StackLayout>

                <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                    <Image src={{item.iconName}} stretch="none" class="item-icon"></Image>
                    <Label class="item-category" [text]="item.category"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                    <Label class="item-time" text="4 hours ago"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                    <Image src={{item.imageUrl}} stretch="aspectFill" width="100%" height="50%" class="item-image"></Image>
                    <Label class="item-title" [text]="item.title" textWrap="true"></Label>
                </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>     


    <Image src="res://pref_circle" (setupItemView)="showModal($event)" verticalAlignment="bottom" horizontalAlignment="right" minWidth="45"  height ="45" ></Image>
```

I'm using modal custom dialog screen.When coming back from modal dialog, its triggering below code:

**ts file:**

```
    public showModal(args: SetupItemViewArgs) {
    let options = {
        context: {},
        fullscreen: true,
        viewContainerRef: this.vcRef
    };

    this.modal.showModal(ModalComponent, options).then(res => {
        console.log("Res:", res);

        console.log("PrintCategory2", StatusBar.categoryArr);

        let i = args.index;
        let barCategory = StatusBar.categoryArr[i];
        let dataCategory = this.allFeedItems[i].category;

        if (barCategory === dataCategory) {
            args.view.context.visible = false;
        } else {
            args.view.context.visible = true;
        }


    });
```

when clicking on the image I'm triggering showmodel dialog. When getting response from modal dialog, it will trigger this line :  `this.modal.showModal(ModalComponent, options).then(res =>`.

My issue is : When clicking on the modal dialog is not triggering. Because I have added SetUpItemViewArgs in this method : `public showModal(args: SetupItemViewArgs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Solution 1: Using Observable**

This solution is by  using an `BehaviorSubject` (type of observable) and the `async` pipe, and by removing the row item you want to hide in the array. The whole list will be updated everytime you change the value in the subject.

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";

...

public items$: BehaviorSubject<Array<any>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
constructor() {
    //may be it's not in constructor but after you got allFeedItems
    this.items$.next(this.allFeedItems);
}
public hideSomeRow() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.allFeedItems.length; i++) {
        let barCategory = StatusBar.categoryArr[i];
        let dataCategory = this.allFeedItems[i].category;

        if (barCategory === dataCategory) {
            // remove the item from array 
            this.allFeedItems.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    //update to the new value
    this.items$.next([...this.allFeedItems]);
}
```

your view:

```
<ListView [items]="items$ | async" class="list-group">
    <ng-template let-item="item" let-index="index">
        <StackLayout class="card-view" margin="10">

        <StackLayout>

            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                <Image src={{item.iconName}} stretch="none" class="item-icon"></Image>
                <Label class="item-category" [text]="item.category"></Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                <Label class="item-time" text="4 hours ago"></Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <Image src={{item.imageUrl}} stretch="aspectFill" width="100%" height="50%" class="item-image"></Image>
                <Label class="item-title" [text]="item.title" textWrap="true"></Label>

            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>    
<Image (tap)="hideSomeRow()" ... class="item-image"></Image>
```

---

### **Solution 2: Js/ts simple logic**

(hide some row/remove some item, after an action)

You need to store in an array variable the statement of an item if it should be hide or visible.

```
public isVisible: Array<boolean> = [];
public hideSomeRow() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.allFeedItems.length; i++) {
        let barCategory = StatusBar.categoryArr[i];
        let dataCategory = this.allFeedItems[i].category;

        if (barCategory === dataCategory) {
            // remove the item from array 
            this.allFeedItems.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
}
```

Now in your html, nothing to change:

```
<ListView [items]="allFeedItems" class="list-group">
    <ng-template let-item="item" let-index="index">
        <StackLayout class="card-view" margin="10">

        <StackLayout>

            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                <Image src={{item.iconName}} stretch="none" class="item-icon"></Image>
                <Label class="item-category" [text]="item.category"></Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                <Label class="item-time" text="4 hours ago"></Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <Image src={{item.imageUrl}} stretch="aspectFill" width="100%" height="50%" class="item-image"></Image>
                <Label class="item-title" [text]="item.title" textWrap="true"></Label>

            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>    
<Image (tap)="hideSomeRow()" ... class="item-image"></Image>
```

> Note: you may use ChangeDetectorRef to update view

Comment: please check my edited post.My issue is when clicking on the image, it was not triggering the modal dialog.

Comment: Why do you changed the  question :-/ ? Why do you add setupItemView in Image, why not (tap)? Even you use some code from my answer, now I'm lost with your need, because you wanted to hide some rows only :(

Comment: extremely sorry.I have implemented all your answers in edited post. When clicking on the image only I need to perform hide and show listitem.

Comment: When clicking on the image => (tap)="showModal()", not setupItemView

Comment: It will not work, you want something: click on modal => hide some item? in this case you dont need the setupItemView in listview, solution is to set an array like `isVisible: Array<boolean> = [];` and setting by index in this variable if an item should be visible or not. You will get: `isVisible = [true, true,..., false]` then using it in the view

Comment: @Stephen I updated the solution, try the solution 2 because solution 1 wouldnt work with your need (after calling the modal)

Comment: I tried your second solution.it working fine for 1st and 2nd listview row item. But when I scrolled down, 3rd and 4th list item is not working fine. I think when recycling listview hide and show is not working for 3rd, 4th,.etc.listview items.

Comment: @Stephen I added a 3rd solution, renamed it do solution 1 because it is the best in my opinion

Comment: And I removed the customising listview (setupItemView) from solution since it's only during building the list

Comment: As I see, your solution is working fine with listview hide and show items. I used this solution(Solution 2: Js/ts simple logic).

Comment: Thanks to you too